# Using an asterisk in an annotation textstring

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, annotation, text

I try to add an asterisk to the annotation (converted to shapefile), to indicate in my report that there is missing data for this polygon. However when I add the asterisk to the string and press "Toepassen" (in English it would be something like apply) nothing happens. How can I make the asterisk appear in the annotation?

[image]

Comment: Adding a regular textbox with only an asterisk is possible, and provided a work-around for now.